# What is the keystore type for keystore generated from android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to know the key alias of my recently created .jks keystore file .
Have tried with command : keytool -list -v - keystore keystorename.jks

but got java.io.IOException :Invalid keystore formatt

Is there a seperate command for .jks files?

Comment: What *is* the keystore format? It clearly isn't JKS.

Comment: the file extension is .jks , that's what i meant

Comment: Do you have a store password and a key password?

Comment: yes ,I do remember the passwords

Comment: Sorry that the answer didn't help, not sure why it would not be working for you.  Maybe the keystore file is corrupted, try generating it again.

Comment: @DanielNugent  that is the whole issue dude project is already live in playstore can't generate new keystore now..